# How to submit a PyDeequ job from Jupyter Notebook to a Spark/YARN

Tags: python, amazon-deequ

How to configure the environment to submit a PyDeequ job to a Spark/YARN (client mode) from a Jupyter notebook. There is no comprehensive explanation other than those using the environment. How to setup the environment to use with non-AWS environment?

There are errors caused such as `TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable` if just follow the example e.g. [Testing data quality at scale with PyDeequ](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/testing-data-quality-at-scale-with-pydeequ/).

```
from pydeequ.analyzers import *
analysisResult = AnalysisRunner(spark) \
    .onData(df) \
    .addAnalyzer(Size()) \
    .addAnalyzer(Completeness("review_id")) \
    .addAnalyzer(ApproxCountDistinct("review_id")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Mean("star_rating")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Compliance("top star_rating", "star_rating >= 4.0")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Correlation("total_votes", "star_rating")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Correlation("total_votes", "helpful_votes")) \
    .run()
                    
analysisResult_df = AnalyzerContext.successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult)
analysisResult_df.show()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_499599/1388970492.py in <module>
      1 from pydeequ.analyzers import *
----> 2 analysisResult = AnalysisRunner(spark) \
      3     .onData(df) \
      4     .addAnalyzer(Size()) \
      5     .addAnalyzer(Completeness("review_id")) \

~/home/repository/git/oonisim/aws/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydeequ/analyzers.py in onData(self, df)
     50         """
     51         df = ensure_pyspark_df(self._spark_session, df)
---> 52         return AnalysisRunBuilder(self._spark_session, df)
     53 
     54 

~/home/repository/git/oonisim/aws/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydeequ/analyzers.py in __init__(self, spark_session, df)
    122         self._jspark_session = spark_session._jsparkSession
    123         self._df = df
--> 124         self._AnalysisRunBuilder = self._jvm.com.amazon.deequ.analyzers.runners.AnalysisRunBuilder(df._jdf)
    125 
    126     def addAnalyzer(self, analyzer: _AnalyzerObject):

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HADOOP_CONF_DIR

Copy the contents of `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`  from the Hadoop/YARN master node to the local host and set the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable to point to the directory.

- [Launching Spark on YARN](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#launching-spark-on-yarn)

> Ensure that **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** or **YARN_CONF_DIR** points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. These configs are used to write to HDFS and connect to the YARN ResourceManager. The configuration contained in this directory will be distributed to the YARN cluster so that all containers used by the application use the same configuration.

```
os.environ['HADOOP_CONF_DIR'] = "/opt/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2/etc/hadoop"
```

## PYTHONPATH

### pyspark

Need to be able to load the **pyspark** python modules. Install **pyspark** with pip or conda which installs the Spark runtime libraries (for standalone). Or copy the **pyspark** python modules `$SPARK_HOME/python/lib` from the Spark installation.

- [PySpark Getting Started](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html)

> Ensure the SPARK_HOME environment variable points to the directory where the tar file has been extracted. Update PYTHONPATH environment variable such that it can find the PySpark and Py4J under SPARK_HOME/python/lib. One example of doing this is shown below:
>
> ```
> export PYTHONPATH=$(ZIPS=("$SPARK_HOME"/python/lib/*.zip); IFS=:; echo >"${ZIPS[*]}"):$PYTHONPATH
> ```

```
sys.path.extend([
    "/opt/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip",
    "/opt/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip"
])
```

### PyDeequ

Install **pydeequ** with pip or conda. Note that this is not enough to use pydeequ.

## Deequ JAR files

### Deequ jar to the library path

To use the PyDeequ, need the deequ jar file. Download the one for the Spark/Deequ version from the [Maven repository com.amazon.deequ](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.deequ/deequ).

```
import os
import sys

root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.getcwd()))
deequ_jar = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazon/deequ/deequ/2.0.0-spark-3.1/deequ-2.0.0-spark-3.1.jar"
classpath = f"{root}/jar/deequ-2.0.0-spark-3.1.jar"

!wget -q -O $classpath $deequ_jar
```

## Spark Session

Specify the Deequ jar files to the Spark jar properties as specified in:

- [Deequ Analyzers Basic Tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/blob/master/tutorials/analyzers.ipynb)
- [TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable when running pydeequ](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/issues/1)

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .master('yarn') \
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client') \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath) \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord) \
    .config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord) \
    .config('spark.debug.maxToStringFields', 100) \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '2g') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

## Deequ Job

Using the excerpt of the Amazon product review data.
[image]

```
df = spark.read.csv(
    path=f"file:///{root}/data/amazon_product_reviews.csv.gz",
    header=True,
)
df.printSchema()
-----
root
 |-- review_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- marketplace: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- star_rating: string (nullable = true)
 |-- total_votes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- helpful_votes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_category: string (nullable = true)
```

```
from pydeequ.analyzers import *
analysisResult = AnalysisRunner(spark) \
    .onData(df) \
    .addAnalyzer(Size()) \
    .addAnalyzer(Completeness("review_id")) \
    .addAnalyzer(ApproxCountDistinct("review_id")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Mean("star_rating")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Compliance("top star_rating", "star_rating >= 4.0")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Correlation("total_votes", "star_rating")) \
    .addAnalyzer(Correlation("total_votes", "helpful_votes")) \
    .run()
                    
analysisResult_df = AnalyzerContext.successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult)
analysisResult_df.show()
-----
21/08/16 11:17:00 WARN package: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
                                                                                
+-------+---------------+-------------------+------+
| entity|       instance|               name| value|
+-------+---------------+-------------------+------+
| Column|      review_id|       Completeness|   1.0|
| Column|      review_id|ApproxCountDistinct|1040.0|
|Dataset|              *|               Size|1000.0|
| Column|top star_rating|         Compliance| 0.657|
+-------+---------------+-------------------+------+
```